# Add curlpp to cmake project

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, curlpp

I am trying to do a project in C++ with the help of curlcpp and cmake, but I am unable to compile the project.

I am new to CMakeLists and it is quite difficult to understand how to add the stuff you require to make your project work. I basically usually copy what I can find in other posts without really understanding how they work; tutorial and documentation is usually either too basic or to complex. To make things worse, I have the impression that each library is added differently so when there is a new one to add the only way I have to add it is to search for previous post asking how to do it. In this case I was unable to find anything that helped me.

**So here is what I have done:**

After installing curlpp and curl with homebrew

```
brew install curl
brew install curlpp
```

I write my project:

Cmakelists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(stock_analysis)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -std=c++11")


######## BOOST STUFF ########
#DELETE NEXT LINE
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)

# set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON) # only find static libs
# set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
# set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
                   filesystem
)

######## CURL STUFF ########
include(FindCURL)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
if(CURL_FOUND)
 message(STATUS "Found CURL version: ${CURL_VERSION_STRING}")
 message(STATUS "Using CURL include dir(s): ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
 message(STATUS "Using CURL lib(s): ${CURL_LIBRARIES}")
else()
 message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find CURL")
endif()




SET(HEADERS
   include
)

SET(SOURCE_FILES
  src/main.cpp
  src/analyse.cpp
  src/helpers.cpp
  src/simulation.cpp
  src/data.cpp
)

include_directories(${HEADERS}
                   ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                   ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(app ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(app
       ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
       ${CURL_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Function in data.cpp (I basically copy the example in curlcpp webpage):

```
#include "data.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>

using namespace curlpp::options;


void fetchData(){

  try
    {
    // That's all that is needed to do cleanup of used resources (RAII style).
        curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

        // Our request to be sent.
        curlpp::Easy myRequest;

        // Set the URL.
        myRequest.setOpt<Url>("http://example.com");

        // Send request and get a result.
        // By default the result goes to standard output.
        myRequest.perform();
  }

  catch( curlpp::RuntimeError &e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    catch( curlpp::LogicError &e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "curlpp::OptionBase::OptionBase(CURLoption)", referenced from:
      curlpp::Option<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::Option(CURLoption, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::OptionBase::~OptionBase()", referenced from:
      curlpp::Option<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::Option(CURLoption, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in data.cpp.o
      curlpp::Option<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::~Option() in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(char const*)", referenced from:
      curlpp::Option<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::updateMeToOption(curlpp::OptionBase const&) in data.cpp.o
      curlpp::OptionTrait<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, (CURLoption)10002>::updateHandleToMe(curlpp::internal::CurlHandle*) const in data.cpp.o
      curlpp::Option<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::getValue() const in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::RuntimeError::~RuntimeError()", referenced from:
      curlpp::UnsetOption::~UnsetOption() in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::libcurlRuntimeAssert(char const*, CURLcode)", referenced from:
      void curlpp::internal::CurlHandle::option<void*>(CURLoption, void*) in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::Easy::perform()", referenced from:
      StockAnalysis::fetchData(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool const&) in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::Easy::Easy()", referenced from:
      StockAnalysis::fetchData(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool const&) in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::Easy::~Easy()", referenced from:
      StockAnalysis::fetchData(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool const&) in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::Cleanup::Cleanup()", referenced from:
      StockAnalysis::fetchData(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool const&) in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::Cleanup::~Cleanup()", referenced from:
      StockAnalysis::fetchData(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool const&) in data.cpp.o
  "curlpp::OptionBase::operator<(curlpp::OptionBase const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for curlpp::OptionTrait<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, (CURLoption)10002> in data.cpp.o
      vtable for curlpp::Option<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > in data.cpp.o
  "typeinfo for curlpp::LogicError", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table0 in data.cpp.o
  "typeinfo for curlpp::OptionBase", referenced from:
      curlpp::Option<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::updateMeToOption(curlpp::OptionBase const&) in data.cpp.o
      typeinfo for curlpp::Option<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > in data.cpp.o
  "typeinfo for curlpp::RuntimeError", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table0 in data.cpp.o
      typeinfo for curlpp::UnsetOption in data.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [app] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I had previously followed the next thread:
[Linking curl in a project using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657931/linking-curl-in-a-project-using-cmake)

Adding *curlcpp* to *target_link_libraries()* in the cmakelists just makes another error appear:

```
ld: library not found for -lcurlpp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [app] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

By the way, I do not understand why curlcpp appears from no where and without the traditional cmakelists notation **${Some_variable}**

Comment: You link with the cURL library, but not the cURLpp library which is separate and distinct from cURL.

Comment: @squareskittles I tried following the info in the link but it does not work. I will edit the question to add the error too.

Comment: I think you might be looking to import the library into CMake, or at least tell CMake where to look for the installed library. See the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774593/3987854) question.

Comment: The solution actually works, but it is not at all elegant nor portable. Calling link_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/curlpp/0.8.1/lib/) which is where homebrew installed the library makes the compilation work. However I still don't understand why I have to put in target_link_libraries curlpp instead of libcurlpp which is the name of the library (libcurlpp.a and libcurlpp.dylib can be found on the path)

Comment: @Alexis the library curlpp does not support being used with CMake, unfortunately. You'll have to either add the support to the library or write a find module file. Either of those are not easy task, but you can find more info there: [It's Time To Do CMake Right](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thank you for the feedback. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

use curlpp like below(minimum code):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(testCurlPP LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(CURLPP REQUIRED curlpp)

add_executable(testCurlPP
  main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(testCurlPP
    ${CURLPP_LDFLAGS}
    )
```

**Note: dont forget to building and installing curlpp before using that in projects.**

building(take last release) [curlpp](https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp):

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j8
sudo make install
```

add its location to environment variables:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```